# Spring Reactive webflux filter, for validating request body

Tags: spring, filter, spring-webflux, reactive

I need to fetch request body and validate its hash in filter. If validation fails whole request should fail. Currently even if validation is failing and exception is being logged in console but controller succeeds in processing. Below is my code. Its like it is creating 2 separate threads for controller and filter body validator.

Filter

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class HmacFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String clientName = getClientName(exchange.getRequest());
        Mono<Client> clientMono = clientService.getClient(clientName);
        ServerHttpRequestDecorator decorator = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                return super.getBody().doOnNext(buffer -> {
                    String body = String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer.asByteBuffer()));
                    String hmac = getHmac(exchange.getRequest());
                    clientMono.subscribe(client -> {
                        String calculatedHmacValue = HmacCalculator.calculateHmac(body, client.getSecretKey());
                        log.info("client : {}, hmac received: {}, hmac calculated: {}, request {}",
                                client.getName(), hmac, calculatedHmacValue, body);
                        if (StringUtils.isBlank(calculatedHmacValue) || !calculatedHmacValue.equals(hmac)) {
                            log.error("hmac doesn't match for client : {} the request {}, hmac received: {}, hmac calculated: {}",
                                    client.getName(), hmac, body, calculatedHmacValue);
                            throw new OrderServiceException(OrderServiceExceptionCode.INVALID_HMAC);
                        }
                        log.info("hmac matched successfully client {}", client.getName());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build());
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class OrderHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> placeOrder(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<OrderRequest> orderRequestMono = request.bodyToMono(OrderRequest.class);
        String clientName = getClient(request);
        Mono<OrderCreateResponse> orderCreateResponseMono = orderRequestMono
                .flatMap(orderRequest -> inventoryValidationService.initiateOrder(orderRequest, clientName))
                .flatMap(orderService::createOrder)
                .flatMap(sellerService::placeOrder)
                .flatMap(this::getOrderCreateResponse);

        Mono<ApiResponse<OrderCreateResponse>> successResponse = ApiResponse.createSuccessResponse(orderCreateResponseMono);
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(successResponse, ApiResponse.class);
    }

}
```